# Timeout async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я промисифицирую функцию `function example() {...}` с помощью `util.promisify()`, затем в `async function() {...}` использую `await example()`. Мне необходимо, чтобы спустя заданное время программа переставала ждать, необходимо установить `timeout`. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, воспользоваться https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-timeout

```
var pt = require('promise-timeout');

var examplePromise = example();
var timeOut = 1000;

pt.timeout(examplePromise, timeOut)
  .then(function (exampleRes) {
    console.log('example() returns result', exampleRes);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    if (err instanceof pt.TimeoutError) {
      console.error('example() timeout', err);
    }
  });
```